# Combining htaccess redirect rules

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have 2 separate htaccess and i need to combine them into one but im not sure how to do it. These are my htaccess:

1.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

2.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ //([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /folder/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Should i just put them together inside the same ifmodule? I already tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ //([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /folder/%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I did so but im afraid it didnt work. I still get a redirection loop error.

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove multiple slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)//+(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

- Test this in a new browser to avoid old 301 cache.
- If redirection loop occurs then open Firebug and the visit a URL with 2 slashes and check in Net tab what redirects you get.

Comment: I get 21 redirections to the same URL.

Comment: What is the URL that you entered in browser? Are there more rules or this is the only code?

Comment: I entered mydomain.com//somepage and all the redirects are for that same page. I dont have any other rules, only the ones you posted.

Comment: Hmm, you know, i think is because i have special characters in my URLs because after the redirection i get a 404 error and if i look at the URL is something like mydomain.com/%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A4%E3%83%BB%E3%/

Comment: Ok what is an example URL with special chars? You can add `B` flag also next to `NE` flag.

Comment: Like this: mydomain.com/日本語

Comment: But there is only 1 slash there so it should work. Also see updated rule

Comment: with 1 slash the URL is correct, the problem is that at some point, the user is redirected to mydomain.com//日本語 and this one wont work, thats why i need a rule to redirect that back to mydomain.com/日本語. I have to go now, i will try your code and tell you tomorrow. thank you.

Comment: Actually rather than removing the double slash i need to insert the name of the directory there. The problem is that the name is in special characters and that seems to have problems when parsing. My URLS are like this: mydomain.com/folder/pagename but for some reason after submitting some forms you are redirected to either: mydomain.com//pagename or mydomain.com/pagename and neither will work as long as the directory name is missing.

Comment: But none of your rules are adding/removing directory name. DO you have more rules than what is shown here?

Comment: This one is supposed to be adding it: 'RewriteRule ^ /folder/%1 [L,R=301]'

Comment: But that will only work if there are 2 slashes in original URI not always.

Comment: In that case what is the problem? My rule is working perfectly fine when there are 2 slashes in the URL. `mydomain.com/日本語` **will not be affected** by 2 slash rule. Even if you comment out my 302 rule `mydomain.com/日本語` will behave same.